# Checkpoint and TAPOS : implemented in Tezos?

Tags: proof-of-stake

Tezos position paper describes checkpointing (not the disk storage check pointing coming in `tezos-node` soon) and TAPOS as protection against long range attacks.

Are they implemented somehow in the current eco-system?

Answer (score 1):

I found an effort for the checkpoint:

https://tezosbtc.com/ burns Tezos block hashes into Bitcoin blockchain.

The following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEjxfpREhzQ&feature=youtu.be explains the details.